# Setting up MySite and Not Seeing it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site

Setting up a SharePoint 2019 environment. Using SSL. User Service is working fine, sync is pulling in all the users in my AD. Set up separate web app for MySite set up Self-Service. Using custom permission policy that allows for site creation. Set up Managed Path with Wildcard inclusion. Created site collection using the My Site Host template. Did a iisreset even a full reboot. I think I covered all the bases yet when I go to my home site and drop the menu down under my name I don't see About Me. Anyone have any thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured My Site settings for the User Profile service application.

Refer to the following article about how to configure My Sites in SharePoint Server step by step:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/configure-my-sites